# How to place cursor at the beginning of a cell of QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using following PyQt code and The requirement the cursor should blink  at the start of cell  0,1

```
import sys 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

data = {'col1':['1','2','3'], 'col2':['4','5','6'], 'col3':['7','8','9']}

class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
         QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
         self.data = data
         self.setmydata()
         self.resizeColumnsToContents()
         self.resizeRowsToContents()
         self.setCursorPosition()

    def setmydata(self):

        horHeaders = []
        for n, key in enumerate(sorted(self.data.keys())):
            horHeaders.append(key)
            for m, item in enumerate(self.data[key]):
              newitem = QWidget()
              self.setCellWidget(m, n, newitem)
              self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horHeaders)

    def setCursorPosition(self):
         wid = self.cellWidget(0,1)
         wid.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.WaitCursor))
         wid.setFocus()
```

The requirement is to blink the cursor at the start of cell  0,1. The lines in method setCursorPosition does not help me  . Can some one help me with the solution

Comment: Done. Please comment now for the solution

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you are setting a QWidget as a cellwidget that does not handle a cursor, and less a blinking cursor. So you should not use QWidget, maybe QLineEdit should be a better option although I find it unnecessary to use cellwidget since it is enough to open the editor that comes by default using the `edit()` method.

```py
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem


class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(MyTable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.data = data
        self.setCustomData()
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()

        index = self.model().index(0, 1)
        self.edit(index)

    def setCustomData(self):
        labels = list(self.data.keys())
        self.setColumnCount(len(labels))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels)

        for i, (key, value) in enumerate(self.data.items()):
            for j, v in enumerate(value):
                if j >= self.rowCount():
                    self.insertRow(self.rowCount())
                it = QTableWidgetItem(v)
                self.setItem(j, i, it)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = {"col1": ["1", "2", "3"], "col2": ["4", "5", "6"], "col3": ["7", "8", "9"]}
    w = MyTable(data)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```